# UIButton is not affected by UITapGestureRecoginzer.

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a `UIImageView` (userInteractionEnabled) `UIButton` and `UITextField` both are subviews of superview, which has a `UITapGestureRecognizer` add to it. So my `superview` and `UIImageView` are **responds** to tap gestures but `UIButton` and `UITextField` **ignores** it. Is it a policy of UITapGestureRecognizer added to superview of this is my fault? Does anyone know about this situation?

This is my code with view subviews and gestureRecognizer

```
 @objc   func tapBlurButton(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("Please Help!")
    endEditing(true)

}


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
   //     backgroundColor = UIColor.green

    addSubview(logoImageView)
   // addSubview(skipButton)
   addSubview(emailTextField)
   addSubview(passwordTextField)
    addSubview(loginButton)
     observeKeyboardNotifications()


 //   logoImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    logoImageView.anchorWithConstantsToTop(centerYAnchor, left: nil  , bottom: nil, right: nil, topConstant: -230, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0)
    logoImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 160).isActive = true
    logoImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 160).isActive = true
    logoImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true

    emailTextField.anchorWithConstantsToTop(logoImageView.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, topConstant: 8, leftConstant: 32, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 32)
    emailTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    passwordTextField.anchorWithConstantsToTop(emailTextField.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, topConstant: 8, leftConstant: 32, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 32)
    passwordTextField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    loginButton.anchorWithConstantsToTop(passwordTextField.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, topConstant: 16, leftConstant: 32, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 32)
    loginButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(LoginCell.tapBlurButton(_:))))
    isUserInteractionEnabled = true

 }
```

I saw other answers they are just tells how to workaround it , but they don't thouch on real reason why it happens, moreover no one refers to docs that tell about this issue exactly. So my question does not asks how to avoid it or how to resolve it, i want to know why it happens, and am i right when i suspect UIkit of doing that so this not my fault or i am wrong a had missed something?

Comment: @Agent Smith please first try to read question before marking my question as duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a really simple and helpful article from Apple. And to understand what you want you should look at the **Responder Chain** concept.

[Understanding Event Handling, Responders, and the Responder Chain](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/understanding_event_handling_responders_and_the_responder_chain)

Basically, if you want to understand why your `UIImageView` **responds** to taps, but `UIButton` and `UITextField` **don't do it**, there is a simple explanation. `UIButton` and `UITextField` are `UIControl`'s subclasses, but `UIImageView` is not, it's only `UIResponder`'s subclass. So, every `UIControl` uses **The Target-Action Mechanism**, but a `UIResponder` doesn't do it.

[UIControl docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol)

[image]

And the documentation says:

> Controls communicate directly with their associated target object
>   using action messages. When the user interacts with a control, the
>   control calls the action method of its target object—in other words,
>   it sends an action message to its target object. Action messages are
>   not events, but they may still take advantage of the responder chain.
>   When the target object of a control is nil, UIKit starts from the
>   target object and walks the responder chain until it finds an object
>   that implements the appropriate action method.

So, it means that **by default** when you click on a `UIControl` object, it doesn't propagate that event to the superview to handle it. Controls override default `UIResponder` behavior. But when you click on a `UIResponder`, it sends the event to the superview to handle it, the touch falls through. So, `UIKit` does that and usual `UITapGestureRecognizer`s don't go through `UIControl`s by default, since controls have their set of preset events and use another mechanism of handling them. But when you disable `UIControl`'s ability to interact with user taps, your superview tap gesture recognizer will respond.

In your case, if you set that, your `func tapBlurButton(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)` will be called even if you press the button, because that button won't try to handle the event and the touch will just fall through to the superview.

```
loginButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Comment: you actually did not explained why it happens so. you just gave me hierarchy and an excerpt that do not actually has in common with real answer and real explanation. thanks for hierarchy, but actually nothing there else deals with question. I just made some statements without proof.  Matt Neuburg will help you IOS 11 pg. 252.

Comment: One method to resolve this problem is `tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false` . And this will make the button and the tap gesture both respond. But would you please explain how this works.